# Possible division by zero in integration by u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

When I was solving the indefinite integral $\int x^2(x^3-7)^3\ dx$, my working was as follows:

Let $u=x^3-7$, then $dx=\frac{1}{3x^2}du$.

Hence, $\int x^2u^3\frac{1}{3x^2}\ du=\frac{1}{3}\int u^3\ du=\frac{u^4}{12}+C=\frac{(x^3-7)^4}{12}+C$.

However, during the u-substitution we get $dx=\frac{1}{3x^2}du$. If $x=0$, then wouldn't that mean we would be diving by zero?

So when we go ahead to find a definite integral with $x=0$ in the limit, why is it okay to ignore the fact that we are dividing by zero?

Comment: Because it is cancelled out by the other factor of $x^2$ present in the integral. For instance, the function
$$f(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)}$$
Isn't defined at $1$, but the integral $\int_0^2 f(x)\mathrm dx$ is still perfectly well defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may avoid dividing by zero if instead of $$dx=\frac{1}{3x^2}du$$ consider $$ du = 3x^2 dx $$ and substitute $$ x^2dx = \frac {1}{3} du$$